# how to avoid mouse pressevent when mouseDoubleClickEvent in qgraphicsitem

Tags: qt

is it possible to avoid the mousePress event call when we doubleClick the item. im having two distinguished  different selection to be done with mousePress and mouse double click. when im double clicking the item the mousePress event propagates and then it is moving to mouse double click .  even i have to emit different signals with mouse press and double click . is there any way to solve it.

i got it from a forum 
**

> You can't avoid it because there is no way of knowing whether a second
>   click will come after the first one so the first one has to initiate a
>   mouse press event. What you can do is to cheat by starting a timer in
>   mouse press event with a small timeout. If double click event comes
>   then stop the timer and ignore it. Otherwise when the timer fires, you
>   will know that there was no double click and you can handle the event
>   as usual

**

but this doesn't help me in my current scenario .

Comment: Why doesn't it help you? It looks like the answer to your question.

Comment: yeah u r right . actually im emitting a signal before stopping the timer in my  double click . that signal has some long process .. so i moved the timer stop above the signal emitting .. now its working thx ..